# Setup private content for specific users with daily updates

Tags: database, sql, content, private

So I have only found membership plugins which cater for private area where users can access the material after paying depending on their role. I need to make a dashboard kind of area where users can look at their profile, their transactions done in real life (oracle database) which could be fed through csv, xml etc. So the question is how to make a wordpress area where specific users can log in, see their name, account number, items they bought that day. For now, we are sending pdf emails to our clients on a daily basis, so to get the website going, just need private area for each of our client to log in, maybe see their pdf files (uploaded by us). Once the skeleton is in place, possibilities are endless :) Please help!!

Answer (score 0):

Do you want this dashboard to be on the front-end or the back-end (inside `/wp-admin`)?

For the first case you just need to create a page with a [custom page template](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/page-templates/) for it, put all your dashboard logic into that template, and redirect your users to the page after they login (check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8127629/65232) for the hook to use, you will need to place it inside the theme's `functions.php` file).

For the second case - if you want something as part of `/wp-admin` - you need to look into creating a custom WordPress admin page (just search for these terms, there are plenty of tutorials).

Comment: Thank you for answering dalbaeb. Dont care about it being inside /wp-admin at the moment. Need the functionality of users being able to view their daily reports more than them being able to comment on posts. My requirement is actually simpler than that. This is what I have in mind. Have a wordpress table or separate mysql table and have username password, client number, name, address, phone, email, their purchases and selling of items, pdf files. So my client comes to the website, logs in, is able to see his details mentioned above and thats it.

Comment: So a separate table or a table on wp mysql. On the front end, ability to authenticate the user from that database, and once done able to see all the above mentioned details on his user area page. Any plugins like that..?